# Binning a variable and setting bin length

Tags: r

I am trying to bin a variable in r and I'd like to set the width of the bins myself. So, the variable would be binned based on the first column, and I would have have r bin based on the following parameters:

```
bin1 = 0.1
bin2 = 0.4
bin2 = 0.3
bin4 = 0.2

The output would look like this:

var_to_bin  binned_var
1           1
2           2
3           2
4           2
5           2
6           3
7           3
8           3
9           4
10          4
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? The binning functions I find have you set the bin range based on my var_to_bin, but I want r to automatically set the bins into quantiles of pre-specified sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `findInterval`, `quantile`, and `cumsum` like this.

```
dat$newBin <- findInterval(dat$var_to_bin,
                           vec=quantile(dat$var_to_bin, probs=cumsum(myProbs)),
                           rightmost.closed=TRUE) + 1L
```

Here, `findInterval` takes the vector to bin, and a vector of of cut points. The cut point vector is built using `quantile` and feeding it the cumulative sum of your desired probability of your partition. The final argument, rightmost.closed, determines whether the endpoints of each partition should be inclusive (set closed) or exclusive (set open).

This returns

```
dat
   var_to_bin binned_var newBin
1           1          1      1
2           2          2      2
3           3          2      2
4           4          2      2
5           5          2      2
6           6          3      3
7           7          3      3
8           8          3      3
9           9          4      4
10         10          4      4
```

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(var_to_bin = 1:10, binned_var = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("var_to_bin", "binned_var"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

myProbs <- c(.1, .4, .3, .2)
```

Comment: This works great. Could you help me understand what the + 1L does? I didn't see it in the documentation.

Comment: `findInterval` returns integers starting with 0. I added 1 (`1L`) indicates an integer) to return the integers 1 through 4 instead of 0 through 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with cut.

```
var_to_bin = 1:10
as.numeric(cut(var_to_bin, include.lowest=TRUE,
   breaks=quantile(var_to_bin, probs=c(0,0.1,0.5,0.8,1))))
 [1] 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `bin_data()` from [mltools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mltools/index.html).

```
# Here x is your var_to_bin
# We specify the bins end points cumulatively as quantiles.
# The result is an ordered factor whose levels represent the unique bins
# and whose values represent which bin each value of x falls into
# Note that these bins are "left-closed, right open" by default.

bin_data(x = 1:10, bins = c(0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1), binType = "quantile")

 [1] [1, 1.9)   [1.9, 5.5) [1.9, 5.5) [1.9, 5.5) [1.9, 5.5) [5.5, 8.2) [5.5, 8.2) [5.5, 8.2) [8.2, 10]  [8.2, 10] 
Levels: [1, 1.9) < [1.9, 5.5) < [5.5, 8.2) < [8.2, 10]
```